# Sharing opengraph story using FB.Feed

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to figure out how to publish opengraph stories using FB.Feed in Unity3d. We are using the Unity Facebook SDK version 6.2.2.

According to the Facebook docs it is possible to utilize the share dialog to post custom opengraph stories.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios#sharedialog

I know it is possible to post stories with FB.API, but that requires extended permissions from the user, which is not something we want to ask for.

Does anyone have a C# code snippet showing how to use the FB.Feed function to post opengraph stories (including metadata and an image)?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Are you sharing a story with a custom action and object type? If so, you need to specify the actionName parameter when calling FB.Feed. The link you posted was for iOS, but you can find information and code snippets specific to Unity here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Feed